# macOS Sonoma (14.2) NSWindow.windowNumbers contains no visible window ids

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, macos-sonoma

I came across a weird issue after updating from Ventura (13.3) to Sonoma (14.2.1):

```
NSWindow.windowNumbers(options: [.allSpaces, .allApplications])
```

responds with an array of window ids that are clearly **not** current visible windows. Not a single "normal" window (like finder, chrome, terminal console) is in that list. Surprisingly, it doesn't happen on most of the Silicon chip laptops (m1, m2). It hapens only on few Airs, on Intel chip iMac. I wonder if anyone has noticed this. Same devices that have issues with these window numbers worked fine on previous OS versions (Ventura 13.3) and the array of window ids was correct.

```
let apps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
let visibleWindowNumbers = NSWindow.windowNumbers(options: [.allSpaces, .allApplications])
var visibleWindowsInfoDicts = [NSDictionary]()

let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .optionAll)
let windowInfoList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID)! as NSArray

/* Check for onscreen windows only*/
for info_ in windowInfoList {
        
        let info = NSMutableDictionary( dictionary: info_ as! NSDictionary)
        let windowNumber = info[kCGWindowNumber as NSString] as! NSNumber
        
        let idOfAppOwningWindow = (info[kCGWindowOwnerPID as NSString] as! NSNumber).int32Value
    
        let app = apps.first { app in
            app.processIdentifier == idOfAppOwningWindow
        }
        
        if  info[kCGWindowIsOnscreen] as? Bool == true &&
            app != nil &&
            app!.activationPolicy == .regular &&
            info[kCGWindowLayer] as! Int == 0
            && info[kCGWindowAlpha] as! CGFloat > 0 {
            
            if visibleWindowNumbers?.contains(windowNumber) == true  {
                  visibleWindowsInfoDicts.append(info) // --> Never gets called on some devices!
            }
                    
        }
         
    }
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: It might be useful to post the code how you are verifying those window numbers, so we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @soundflix Yep, added a code I'm using to figure out visible windows.

Comment: `apps` declaration is missing, is it `let apps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications`?

Comment: @soundflix Exactly, Added that line in the snippet